# How to loop on a table column?

Tags: robotframework

Badly need your help. In Vehicle ID column, I would like to find a vehicle and once it finds it, it will click on it... How can I do that in Robot Framework? What approach should i be using?

[image: Screeshot]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. To propery help you we will need more details on what you've already tried and what the observed results where. Also it helps if you can provide the relevant bit of HTML source code for your target element.

Comment: To be honest I have not tried anything yet since I don't know what approach i will be applying. I'm a total newbie and since i'm hearing really wonderful things about RF, I would wanna try it out. I just wanna know how am I going to loop around the vehicleID column and once it gets the text that I wanted it to find (in the picture is the one that has a red box), it will automatically click on it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need only just loop on table ?

Comment: Probably... But what are my other options?

Answer (score 1):

For looping in table you can use xpath easily:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Stackoverflow Test
    [Tags]    @InDevelop
    Go To    https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=customers    ${global_timeout}
    :FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    2    8
    \    Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//*[@id="customers"]/tbody/tr[${index}]/td[1]    ${global_timeout}
    \    ${var} =    Get Text    xpath=//*[@id="customers"]/tbody/tr[${index}]/td[1]
    \    Log    ${var}
```

In order to click the correct element, you probably need to compare the variable content with your expected value. That can be done this way:

```
${areYouMyLine} =   Run Keyword and Return Status    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${var}    Island Trading
Run Keyword If     ${areYouMyLine}    Click Elementxpath=//*[@id="customers"]/tbody/tr[${index}]/td[1]
```

And also don't forget to Exit your For Loop since you found your element.

```
Exit For Loop
```

However this is not the best practice. You probably should go to your product team asking for some data attributes which will help you to find your line. Alternatively, if you know your table content, put it into a list and use For In Loop instead. Good stuff about loops can be found here: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/05/robot-framework-tutorial-loops-conditional-execution-and-more/

Comment: never tried this but I think this is what im looking for. Thank you so much for the big help!